# Pokemon GO: Does higher player levels mean higher catch rates

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a feeling that higher levels result in a higher catch rate of higher CP Pokemon

However my brother told me that it does not.

So does higher level equate to higher catch rates?

Comment: I feel the contrary. Higher level means higher level 'mons, meaning lower catch rate. That is even visible in the color of the circles: even Pidgeys and Ratatta's are orange with high CP.

Comment: Pretty sure it's sort of the contrary. I've seen some point with the math behind it, can't remember where though.

Comment: I think he's asking if e.g. a 200 rat is easier to catch at lvl 15 vs lvl 5. Makes sense to me because it should be easier, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has been discussed in the subreddit [/r/TheSilphRoad](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/) which is quite truthworthy, since a lot of discoveries about Pokemon Go data have been discovered there.

As pointed out in this post [*Analysis on Catch Rates and Encounters*](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4vs70r/analysis_on_catch_rates_and_encounters/), the catch rate of an encountered Pokemon is determined by two factors :

- The [Base Capture Rate](http://puu.sh/qW1I5/3fb7abd380.png)<sup>1</sup> of the Pokemon, which only depend on the kind of Pokemon itself.
- The Pokemon level, which depends only on your trainer level.

As you can see in [this array](https://images.nowloading.co/image/upload/c_limit,h_1200,q_auto,w_960/hxf8kbyeidsohxqj9xan.jpg)<sup>1</sup>, the combination of those two elements gives us the final catch rate<sup>2</sup>. We notice that the higher the Pokemon level is, the lower the final catch rate is.

Since the Pokemon's level increases as fast as the trainer's level, **a higher lever trainer will encounter Pokemon with lower Capture Rates.**

What's more (thanks @Kat for pointing out), the combination of the Base Capture Rate and the Pokemon's level being the only thing that defines a Pokemon's catch rate, two trainers encountering the same kind of Pokemon with the same Pokemon will have **the same catch rate**, no matter what the levels of the two trainers are.

---

<sup>1</sup> Those links are extracted from the previously mentionned post [*Analysis on Catch Rates and Encounters*](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4vs70r/analysis_on_catch_rates_and_encounters/)

<sup>2</sup> Note that we don't have informations on how the kind of Pokeball influences the catch rate, but it does not really matter as we can obviously assume that a rarer Pokeball is giving a better catch rate independently from of the Trainer's level.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is asking. Obviously you see harder to catch Pokemon as you level, but what about if you see the same level Pokemon at two different trainer levels? Does it become easier to catch?

Comment: @Kat I *am* answering this question : the combination of the Base Capture Rate and the Pokemon's level are the only thing that defines a Pokemon's catch rate, therefore, two trainers encountering the same kind of Pokemon with the same Pokemon will have the same catch rate, no matter what the levels of the two trainers are.

Comment: The answer of "no, a higher level trainer will have the same catch rate for the same type and level of Pokemon" is implied, but imo it would be improved by making it explicit. Your bolded statement is interesting and good to be included, but it's not directly relevant, so the emphasis seems misplaced. Again imo, OP may feel differently.

Comment: @Kat It's updated!

Comment: Looks great, +1. I wish I had known this when I first started playing. I wouldn't have thrown away so many pokeballs if I'd known they'd get harder to catch as I  leveled.

Answer (score 0):

just to add to Ikaros' answer (would have done it in a comment but can't comment yet)

for a given Pokemon CP, whether it's a high or low CP, the trainer level won't make a difference in the capture rate

Comment: The trainer level will influence how high the CP cap is, which increases the possible CP range of an encountered pokemon. Since higher CP = lower catch rate, a higher trainer level means a lower catch rate for encountered pokemon on average. While trainer level does not directly affect catch rate, it indirectly affects it, so it does make a difference.

Comment: @Vemonus  I agree, I'm just saying that once you're on the encounter screen with a Pokemon, whether you're level 1 or 30 won't influence your catch rate. I just thought that was the question of the OP, as I had that same question before.

Comment: Well that is true, but generally speaking, a level 30 player will have a lower catch rate on average than a level 15 player.

Comment: I'm agreeing with you!